# Should the main method be separate in a separate class?

Tags: java, interfaces, command-line

In Java [main methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4) often do little more than parsing the command line arguments and initializing an object that then takes over, for example:

```
public class FooServer {
    // ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Process arguments ...
        FooServer server = new FooServer(...);
        // Initialize server ...
        server.start();
    }
}
```

I have seen that some software extracts this main method into a separate "main" class (often ending in `Launcher` or `Main`):

```
public class FooServer {
    // ...
}

public class FooServerLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Process arguments ...
            FooServer server = new FooServer(...);
            // Initialize server ...
            server.start();
        }
}
```

The "main" class is closely coupled to the other class, so I suppose the "main" class is separate so that it doesn't pollute the interface of the other class.

I discussed the question with a co-worker and the person was of the opinion that contemporary object-oriented programmers chop up classes into too many small separate classes to pretend that everything is interchangeable while it's not. The person argued that this is a good example of the issue as the sole purpose of the main method is to start an object from the command line and thus is in fact part of its interface.

Are there other objective arguments for against separating the main method into its own class?

Answer (score 4):

The pattern you mentioned isn't necessarily the pattern used in all programs.  For example, if I want to make a program that reads messages, processes them, and sends output somewhere, I might have a `main` structure that's more like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Reader reader = new Reader(args[0]);
    Writer writer = new Writer(args[1]);
    Processor processor = new Processor(args[2]);
    reader.start();
    writer.start();
    processor.start();
    ...
}
```

The gist here being that the thing that is launching parts of my application is not solely using one class, like in your examples.  Here I would likely put the `main` function into a `MyProgramLauncher` class, because it's not directly tied to any single class, and we could potentially be adding more classes in the future(initializing logging, database connection, graphics engine, etc)

`main` is also a logical place to check for all of the preconditions of running your program.  Eg. If you can't connect to your database, you might want to fail early and tell the user to check internet connection settings and try again.

If I have a main method like your `FooServerLauncher`, then I would put it in `FooServer`.  So long as there's one `main` method, and it references nothing other than `FooServer`, then it belongs in the `FooServer` file.  Alternatively, if you have multiple main files that utilize `FooServer`, then they need to be in their own `Launcher` style classes, so that the functionality of each 'executable' of your system remains separate.

Analyzing it with typical design metrics(when compared to having `main` in `FooServer`):

- Readability - If anything is reduced, because the thing doing the execution and the thing being executed are separate.  And in a very literal sense you have to read two different files to understand what's going on.
- Modularity - Increased, but I would say this is following the dogma of 'modularity' to a fault.
- Maintainability - Is also reduced for similar reasons to readability.  While maintaining `FooServer` you likely need to alter `FooServerLauncher`.  I would argue it's much less likely to alter `FooServer` and forget to update `main` as needed if they're in the same file.  Having the separate files introduces 'out of sight, out of mind'.
- Coupling - High, because it's 100% dependent on the implementation of `FooServer`.  In your example, `main` has initialization steps and starts `FooServer`, which depending on your preferences may be too much coupling.
- Cohesion - I would say low, for the same reason we have high coupling.  If everything in `main` exists to do something tied to `FooServer`, then the logical place to put `main` is in `FooServer`.

For a couple of these I think you could argue they stay the same, but I'm not quickly coming up with ways in which they're improved.  So, all things considered, having `main` in a separate file seems to be equal-to or less-than having it in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, almost everything is an object, so main() must has to be declared somewhere obviously.  Its concern is distinct from the rest of our class(which defines some data and behaviour that we are trying to encapsulate), which is getting the program ready to execute the whole thing.

In my own opinion main should not be pushed with the other data and behavior of a class.  The main method's concern is with running our program.  It will return to logic necessary that is declared inside of it's body.  With that being said I would go ahead and keep it away from any other class and/or logic in your program.